# wpf drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, drag-n-drop

wpf пытаюсь перетащить одну картинку и дропнуть её в другой блок image.

При нажатии на картинку с котом вызывается mousedown и следующий код

```
private void GetImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Image lbl = sender as Image;
        global_sender = lbl;

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Source, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

Затем при дропе вызывается след. код(только видимо не вызывается)

```
private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Image)sender).Source = global_sender.Source;
    }


 private void Image_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

Не могу найти ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну и xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="623,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128"/>
    <Button Content="Назад" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,385,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="36" Click="BackPage"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="ClothList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="368" Margin="18,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MouseDown="GetImage"/>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="317,82,321,240">
        <Image x:Name="Imagehead" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="108" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropImage" DragEnter="Image_DragEnter"/>
    </Border>
    <Image x:Name="CatImage" Source="cat.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="99" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Margin="504,82,0,0" MouseDown="GetImage"/>
</Grid>`
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Drag and Drop в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769927/drag-and-drop-%d0%b2-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что элемент `Image`, на который должный дропится данные - прозрачный для мыши. Один из вариантов - дропить на `Border` и поставить ему какой-нибудь `Background` (например, `White`) но применять картинку к его ребенку:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropImage">
    <Image Height="108" Width="123" />
</Border>
<Image Source="cat.png" Height="99" Width="132" MouseDown="GetImage" />
```

В таком случае драггинг должен выглядеть как:

```
private void GetImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;
    var data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var border = (Border)sender;
    var image = (Image)border.Child;
    image.Source = (ImageSource)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource));
}
```

Для дальнейшего обучения я бы вам порекомендовал изучить паттерн `MVVM`. С помощью него и `Behavior`-ов можно сделать более красивое Drag&Drop решение.

Comment: Можно ли данный код как-нибудь применить к картинкам, которые находятся в listbox