# Drag and Drop в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать Drag and drop для файлов? Я искал в гугле, полной инструкции не нашёл, есть какие-то обрывки кода и инструкций.

Нужно чтобы при перетаскивании в прямоугольник файла получалось его название и расширение.

Если не хотите, можете не писать код полностью, а хотя бы написать из чего исходить и как считать название полученного файла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос еще актуален то можно так

```
<Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="3"  
                BorderBrush="LightBlue" 
                Margin="50" 
                PreviewDrop="Border_Drop"
                Background="#696969"
                AllowDrop="True">

        </Border>
    </Grid>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Border_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            MessageBox.Show(files[0]);
        }

    }
```

Выведи полный путь к фалу с расширением.А там уже из строки выудиш имя файла и расширение через

Comment: Обновил ответ. м